# are "Look directly into his eyes" and "Look direct into his eyes" the same?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[direct(a)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/direct_1?q=direct) *happening or done without involving other people, actions, etc. in between*
and we can form it into an adverb "**directly**"

Ex: *look directly into his eyes*

but "**directly**" is also an adverb

[direct(adv)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/direct_3): without involving other people

are "**Look directly into his eyes**" and "**Look direct into his eyes**" the same?

I would think "**Look direct into his eyes**" is not common or strange but I am not sure although you can see 800 results when googling "**Look direct into his eyes**"

Comment: In "Look *directly* into his eyes.", *directly* is describing the act of looking (as an adverb modifying a verb). In "Look *direct* into his eyes", *direct* describes a line of sight into his eyes. As such, it modifies like an adjective.

Comment: Adding some actual examples using "direct" would be helpful.

Comment: "direct" could mean the same as "directly" if it's a flat adverb. But the question of what can be a flat adverb is not an exact science, sometimes it even feels ambiguous since there's no agreement among grammarians, and dialect and habit also influences the usage of these words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not everybody knows the difference between an adverb and an adjective. For some words like **fast**, everybody agrees that the same word works as both adjective or adverb- it's called a flat adverb. For other words, the distinction is not so clear. In informal American English, many more words are used as flat adverbs:

> I'm doing really well. - *formal AmE, all BrE*
>   I'm doing real good. - *informal AmE*

According to this definition of [direct](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/direct), the adjectival meaning would have an appropriate meaning in this context but the adverbal meaning would not: the adverb [directly](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/directly) has the appropriate meaning.

**direct into his eyes** is therefore using an adjective where an adverb should be used. This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=directly%20into%20his%20eyes%2C%20direct%20into%20his%20eyes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdirectly%20into%20his%20eyes%3B%2Cc0) shows that the adverbal form is quite common but finds no instances of the adjectival form.

Comment: You completely forgot about flat adverbs. "real" is one of them in your example. In fact there's no definite list of flat adverbs (not even grammarians can agree on one) , today it's a question of dialect and habit.

Comment: @Korvin: point taken, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick took Jane by the elbows and looked directly into her eyes.

When you look straight at someone/something or into someone's eyes, you usually use the adverb directly. It's not common to use the "direct" in this sense, though it can also be used as an adverb.