# Either direct or directly

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

> I came **direct** to my residence from the airport.
>
> I came **directly** to my residence from the airport.

Comment: Many consider "came direct" to be ungrammatical. Other than that, there is no difference.

Comment: Pedants might say only the explicitly adverbial ***-ly*** form is "valid" here, but that's just because they're pedants. Most ordinary native speakers are quite happy to treat ***direct*** here as a "flat adverb". See [Usage of 'quick' as adverb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94713/usage-of-quick-as-adverb), as asked here previously.

Comment: ...even more specifically...  Does this answer your question? [Are "Look **directly** into his eyes" and "Look **direct** into his eyes" the same?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121635/are-look-directly-into-his-eyes-and-look-direct-into-his-eyes-the-same)